# React: updating react-hook-form via react-day-picker doesn't rerender component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-day-picker, radix-ui

I'm having troubles finding the right way to write a form.

I'm using shadcn/radix, zod, and react-hook-form.

I have a date picker / calendar, for this I'm using react-day-picker (NOT react-datepicker). My calendar is defined like this:

```
<Calendar
  mode="multiple"
  selected={field.value}
  onSelect={e => { console.log("change!", e); field.onChange(e)}}
  disabled={(date) => date < startOfToday()}
/>
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that React doesn't register that the form has changed (and the component doesn't rerender) if i select an additional day. if i'm selecting the first day from a clean state, it's registered, but the 2nd, 3rd etc get unnoticed. However, the "change! [x, y, z]" *do* get logged.

To check this I've put a `console.log(JSON.stringify({form: form.getValues()}));` on the top of my render function and that never gets printed, only on the first selection

What am I doing wrong?

In general I think I might have a misunderstanding on how to programatically change the `form` values and trigger a rerender.
I've tried using `zod.transform` but I believe that's only called on submit.

A "minimal" reproducible example can be found here (I had to copy over all the used shadcn components): https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bush-rdw4j9

Steps to reproduce:

0. Open the link and display the console at the bottom
1. Open the calendar by pressing "Pick a date"
2. Select a date, e.g. Sep 5th (notice "render!" gets printed as well as the "change!")
3. Select another date, e.g. Sep 6th (notice "render!" does NOT get printed, but "change!" does)

What I expected: I expected the `render!` to be called everytime I selected an additional value
What actually happened: `render!` was only logged for the first selected day, subsequent day selections didn't trigger a rerender, even though the `change!` was logged and, as a consequence, field.onChange called which delegates to `react-hook-form/Controller#onChange` (FormField is a light wrapper around Controller)

Answer (score 0):

`form.watch(['booking_dates'])` did the trick as someone in the Redactiflux Discord pointed out.

However, I've instead found a better way to accomplish what I was trying to do. In hindsight, my question is a bit XY-problem-y.

I wanted the user to be able to select their days and in the background update related fields to those days. However, I noticed this may have been disrupting the user while they're selecting dates. So instead I want to let the user finish selecting in peace, and once the datepicker is closed, those updates will take place. For this, I've simply added a `useReducer`:

```
const [calendarsCloseCount, calendarClosed] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);
useEffect(() => {
  const values = form.getValues();
  form.setValue('booking_dates', _.sortBy(values.booking_dates, _.identity));
  // other update logic here
}, [calendarsCloseCount]);
```

and changed the popover components: `<PopoverContent onCloseAutoFocus={calendarClosed}>`